Is there a way to wait for a specific network call in Selenium for Python?
I'm trying to use Selenium for Python to open Chrome and visit a webpage and would like to do a waitFor that waits for a particular outbound network request from the page I'm visiting to be completed. In an ideal world, there would be a waitForNetworkRequest function like this:
driver = webdriver.get('https://www.somesite.com')
driver.waitForNetworkRequest(url='https://www.othersite.com', status='completed')

Is there anything built into Selenium or other libraries that might achieve this?

As far as I know, there's no way to do this in Selenium without adding on a module like selenium-wire or by running the requests through a proxy you control, so you can detect the outgoing request there.

@Grismar Any info on how to do this in Selenium-wire, or other library, would be appreciated!

StackOverflow is not a place to ask for recommendations, and also not intended to ask people to code for you. I kept my comment short because you asked if it could be done with just Selenium and I think that's going to be very hard (though you might be able to do something clever with JavaScript in the browser), so I think looking for a library on top of Selenium or using a proxy is the right way to go. You should look at what solution you like, read some of the examples or documentation, and try a solution - feel free to ask if you run into trouble. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
